# Send time dependent Email with flow

Tags: email, visual-workflow

I am looking to send an email to a Contact 10 days after a field on an object is updated. Also if another field is updated on that same object, how would I cancel the email from sending? I am trying to accomplish this using a Flow/Visual Workflow (not a workflow or process builder) because the Flow is going to be invoke via Apex. I am very new to flows and I am having confusion with how the "Wait" element works and how it should be populated.

Answer (score 0):

There were two parts to this answer:

1. I used the Wait Element, and used Event conditions to evaluate 10 days after the given date on the object being passed into the flow [image]
2. From there I had the flow call an InvocableMethod in Apex after the ten day wait period. This InvocableMethod takes the necessary information and sends the email using the SingleMessagingEmail service

   ```
   @InvocableMethod
   public static void sendEmail(List<Milestones__c> milestones) {
       Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
       Map<Id, Milestones__c> milestonesToOppMap = new Map<Id, Milestones__c>();
       Map<Id, String> nudgeEmailWhiteListMap = new Map<Id, String>();

       List<Nudge_Email_White_List__c> nudgeEmailWhiteList = [
           SELECT
               Network_Partner__c,
               Email_Template_Id__c
           FROM Nudge_Email_White_List__c
       ];

       for (Nudge_Email_White_List__c newl : nudgeEmailWhiteList) {
           nudgeEmailWhiteListMap.put(newl.Network_Partner__c, newl.Email_Template_Id__c);
       }

       // Assign milestone opportunity Id's to a set and milestones to milestoneMap
       for (Milestones__c milestone : milestones) {
           oppIds.add(milestone.Opportunity__c);
           milestonesToOppMap.put(milestone.Opportunity__c, milestone);
       }

       // Query for all weight watcheer opportunities in oppIds
       // Also include network partners in nudge email white list map
       Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunityMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
               SELECT
                   Id,
                   Name,
                   Last_Completed_Milestone__c,
                   Contact__c,
                   Network_Partner__c
               FROM Opportunity
               WHERE Id IN: oppIds
               AND Network_Partner__c =: nudgeEmailWhiteListMap.keySet()
       ]);

       List<Milestones__c> milestonesWithNextMilestoneNotAchieved = new List<Milestones__c>();
       List<Id> contactsToSendNudgeEmail = new List<Id>();

       // Find the appropriate Milestone for an opp, compare the opp last complete milestone to the applicableMilestone
       // name, if the the value is the same populate appropriate lists for sending nudge email and restarting flow
       for (Opportunity opp : opportunityMap.values()) {
           Milestones__c applicableMilestone = milestonesToOppMap.get(opp.Id);
           if (opp.Last_Completed_Milestone__c == applicableMilestone.Name &&
               (applicableMilestone.Date_Achieved__c > Date.Today().addDays(-21))) {
               milestonesWithNextMilestoneNotAchieved.add(applicableMilestone);
               contactsToSendNudgeEmail.add(opp.Contact__c);
           }
       }

       // Send nudge email and restart Send Email Flow with applicableMilestones
       if (!contactsToSendNudgeEmail.isEmpty()) {
           List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> nudgeEmailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
           Map<Id, EmailTemplate> emailTemplateMap = new Map<Id, EmailTemplate>([
                   SELECT
                       Id
                   FROM EmailTemplate
                   WHERE Id IN: nudgeEmailWhiteListMap.values()
           ]);

           for (Opportunity opp : opportunityMap.values()) {
               // get the value from map and also email template by converting id to string
               Id emailTemplateId = Id.valueOf(nudgeEmailWhiteListMap.get(opp.Network_Partner__c));
               Messaging.SingleEmailMessage nudgeEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
               nudgeEmail.setTemplateId(emailTemplateMap.get(emailTemplateId).Id);
               nudgeEmail.setTargetObjectId(opp.Contact__c);
               nudgeEmailList.add(nudgeEmail);

           }

           // Send nudge emails and restart NudgeEmailWait flow
           if (!nudgeEmailList.isEmpty() &&
               !milestonesWithNextMilestoneNotAchieved.isEmpty()) {
               // Send Emails
               Messaging.SendEmail(nudgeEmailList);

               // Set flow configurations
               Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
               params.put('Milestones', milestonesWithNextMilestoneNotAchieved);

               Flow.Interview.NudgeEmailWait returnValues = new Flow.Interview.NudgeEmailWait(params);
               returnValues.start();
           }

       }

   }
   ```